# How to convert Java String to Teradata DATE and Timestamp

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, teradata

My java code generates two `Strings`:

```
String myDate = "10/10/2013";
String myTimestamp = "2013-10-09 14:30:20";
```

---

I need to feed these values to a `prepared statement`, so that I could upload them using `jdbc` to  `Teradata`

Here is what I tried :

```
String in = " INSERT INTO " + myTab + " VALUES (?,?) "; 

PreparedStatement prst = null; 
prst = connection.prepareStatement(in); 

   // add date
   prst.setDate(1, (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(myDate));

   //add timestamp
   prst.setDate(2, (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(myTimestamp));
```

The above code compiles but does not work. I get an `empty string` error . How can I convert a `String` into `Teradata types DATE, TIMESTAMP` in order to add them to the prepared statement ?

Comment: Your code should work for converting it to a `Date` (in fact the JDBC driver will convert it). Which line gives you that error?

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "empty string error"? I'd expect an exception because you've tried to cast a `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`. Mind you, your code wouldn't compile to start with because of the `"?,?"` part... your SQL isn't a valid string literal, basically. (It's not clear why you've got quotes there at all...)

Comment: Thank you. I get `java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date` When I remove the cast `(Date)` it does not compile at all

Comment: Sorry about the quotes, this is a typo. **The code works fine. I tested it for `INTEGER, DECIMAL VARCHAR`.** But I can't figure out how to convert `java Strings` to `sql type DATE and TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`java.sql.Date` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) that takes a `long`, by using [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) and changing from

```
prst.setDate(1, (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(myDate));
```

to something like

```
prst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
    .parse(myDate)).getTime());
```

and the other one

```
prst.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .parse(myTimestamp)).getTime());
```

Comment: Use java.sql.TimeStamp for your timestamp one look at my post above.

Comment: I added prst.setDate and prst.setTimestamp to my answer above brso05 try copying and pasting exactly what i have it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
prst.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(myDate).getTime()));
```

This will convert your date then create a new sqlDate.

```
prst.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(myTimeStamp).getTime());)
```

for the timestamp use setTimeStamp not setDate.